# Delete rows with 0 for several columns in Matlab (only delete if all the rows contain zero)

Tags: matlab, delete-row

So I want to delete rows of a matrix that contain all zero, but only for specific columns. For example:

```
A = [[0 0 0 0; 1 2 0 4; 2 0 1 1; 0 0 0 0; 1 2 3 4; 0 1 2 3];
```

I want for matrix A to check if the 2th AND 4th columns contain zero's. If this is true: then delete the whole row. So the result should be:

```
A = [1 2 0 4; 2 0 1 1; 1 2 3 4; 0 1 2 3];
```

I wrote something down, but I need to combine these two rows:

```
>>> second_0 = A(:, 2) ~= 0;
>>> fourth_0 = A(:, 4) ~= 0;
>>> keep = secondColIsNonzero & fourthColIsNonzero;
>>> newA = A(keep, :)
newA =
 1     2     0     4
 1     2     3     4
 0     1     2     3
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different from your previous question...

Comment: I just answered this, which he/she asked as a comment, in the 1st question.